# How to use Math.cos() & Math.sin()?

Tags: java, math

I'm using `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` but it returns me unexpected results like these:

```
 Angle   Sin      Cos
 354     0.8414  -0.5403
 352     0.1411   0.98998
 350    -0.958   -0.2836
```

Why I get these results?

Comment: For sine: Float x = (float) Math.sin ( Math.toRadians (270 degree) ) For cos: Float x = (float) Math.sin ( Math.toRadians (90 + 270 degree) )

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Are you trying to use degrees? Keep in mind that `sin` and `cos` are expecting radians.

```
Math.cos(Math.toRadians(354))
```

Answer (score 17):

`Math.cos` and `Math.sin` take [angles in radians](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#cos%28double%29), not degrees. So you can use:

```
double angleInDegree = 354;
double angleInRadian = Math.toRadians(angleInDegree);
double cos = Math.cos(angleInRadian); // cos = 0.9945218953682733
```

Comment: +1 or to use `Math.cos(Math.toRadians(354))`

Answer (score 5):

```
public static double sin(double a)

Parameters:
a - an angle, in radians.
Returns:
the sine of the argument.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this also:

```
degrees *= Math.PI / 180;
Math.cos(degrees)
```

Comment: I think `Math#toRadians()` is more readable but thanks for mentioning that way too ;)

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers fitted my needs. Here's what I had:

A sinus in degree (not radiant).
This is how you turn it back into a degree angle:

```
double angle = Math.toDegree(Math.asin(sinusInDegree));
```

Explanation: If you have 2 sides of a triangle, it's the only solution that worked for me. You can calcluate everything using the normal degree metric, but you have to convert the `Math.asin()` back to degree for the right result. :)