# Java get cos or sin of angle

Tags: java, trigonometry, radians

I have the folling:

```
double angle = 0.0;
double rad = Math.toRadians(angle);
double sinIs = Math.sin(rad);
double cosIs = Math.cos(rad);
```

I would expect the result to be:

```
rad=0.0
sinIs=0
cosIs=1
```

However the return Math.toRadians(0.0) will return

```
rad=2.356194490192345
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. I just tested and `Math.toRadians(0.0) == 0.0`.

Comment: Nope: http://ideone.com/lfas6N.  Though FWIW, that's equivalent to 135 degrees.

Comment: it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951136/how-to-use-math-cos-math-sin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems some issue at your end.
I tested this code

```
public static void main(String a1[]) 
    {
        double angle = 0.0;
        double rad = Math.toRadians(angle);
        double sinIs = Math.sin(rad);
        double cosIs = Math.cos(rad);
        System.out.print("sin-->"+sinIs+"\ncos-->"+cosIs);
    }
```

Output

```
sin-->0.0
cos-->1.0
```

Comment: You're right, I had a mistake in my code.