# How to draw the radius of a circle without it being shorter or larger than the circumference

Tags: java, swing, geometry, trigonometry, custom-painting

I am working on a program in which I want to draw a line from circle's center to its parametric point. But it draws line out of circumference and inside circumference. I want to draw line exactly on circumference according to `X` and `Y` angles.

Circle center points:

```
x = 200
y = 100
radius= 100
```

[image: [here i just want to draw a line for circle center to its circumference.]

```
public SecondActivity(String azim,String ele) {
    initialize();
    setTitle("My WIndow");`

    angle_x = Integer.parseInt(azim);
    angle_y = Integer.parseInt(ele);

    x = 200+r*Math.cos(angle_x);
    y = 100+r*Math.sin(angle_y);      
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    drawCircle(g,200,100,r);
    drawLine(g);
}

public void drawCircle(Graphics g,int x,int y,int r) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawOval(x, y, r*2,r*2);
}
public void drawLine(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;    
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(300.0d,200.0d,x,y));
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a image (made in paint or so) that shows what you are trying to achieve, and one that shows what you have right now?

Comment: Sorry guys ... But please Help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your code (and logic):

1. You're using 2 angles to calculate the `X` and `Y` coords, thus, giving you weird results. As per this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions) image the angle theta is the same for bot coords.

   [image]
2. You're using the angle in degrees, but `Math.cos(angle)` and `Math.sin(angle)` require that the `angle` is given in radians, so, you must convert the angles to radians as like `Math.roRadians(angle)`, as shown in this question: [How to use Math.cos() & Math.sin()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951136/how-to-use-math-cos-math-sin)
3. Not really an error but a suggestion from @MadProgrammer in [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41944799/2180785) to use the Shape API instead of pure `.drawOval` as you did while drawing the line, change `drawOval` to `draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(...))`.
4. You're overriding `paint(Graphics g)` method instead of `paintComponent(Graphics g)` this could cause some issues while painting. Use `JPanels` and override their `paintComponent` method and add those `JPanel`s to your `JFrame`.

Having said all of the above, I came to a good example that follows the above advises as well as solving the issue:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class RadiusDrawer {
    private JFrame frame;
    private int centerX = 50;
    private int centerY = 50;
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private int r = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RadiusDrawer()::createAndShowGui);
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

        frame.add(new MyCircle());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class MyCircle extends JPanel {
        int cx = 0;
        int cy = 0;
        public MyCircle() {
            int angle = 0;

            x = (int) (r * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));
            y = (int) (r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)));

            y *= -1; //We must inverse the Y axis since in Math Y axis starts in the bottom while in Swing it starts at the top, in order to have or angles correctly displayed, we must inverse the axis

            calculateCenter();
        }

        private void calculateCenter() {
            cx = centerX + r;
            cy = centerY + r;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            drawCircle(g2d, centerX, centerY, r);
            drawRadius(g2d);
        }

        private void drawCircle(Graphics2D g2d, int x, int y, int r) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, r * 2, r * 2));
        }

        private void drawRadius(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(cx, cy, cx + x, cy + y));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some screenshots of the output at 0, 60 and 90 degrees.

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me ..But I don't get Why did you declare these variables.                                                                                
          double lineX = 0;
          double lineY = 0;
          double roundedX = 0;
          double roundedY = 0;

Comment: Those were some tests that I was doing, you can safely remove them I forgot to do so... (I already did the edit in the program above as well @AshuAnsari)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to help ^^ keep it up C: BTW I found another error in your program, let me mention it into my answer (See point #4)

Comment: tell me please .

Comment: @AshuAnsari to tell you what? I already added point #4 to my post which is the other error I saw...

Comment: can you help to add JPanel to JFrame so that I could override paintComponent() method

Comment: Because I have override paintComponets() method but now it is not drawing circle and lines.

Comment: Frakcool please help me . An Error is occurring means When I run the Program . it does not show  line at correct angle . but when I run again then it draws line at correct angle.  please help me What should I do to resolve it.

Comment: Again it's `paintComponent` not `paintComponentS`. Since this question was about drawing the radius and it is already solved I invite you to ask a new question with a proper [mcve] so we can help you. I'm in my way to the office, if I see your question when I arrive I'll try to help