# how to override paintComponent method and use with JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have override `paintComponents` method, but when I am using it and run my program then it does not show any circle and lines. Recently frakcool said it is not `paintComponents` method, it is `paintComponent` method. I found out but I didn't get any `paintComponent` method.

This picture shows that i have not got any paintComponent method:

[image: this picture shows that i have not got any paintComponent method.]

Codes are here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                SecondActivity frame = new SecondActivity();
                frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                frame.paintComponents(null);
              //  frame.paint(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    drawCircle(g2d,centerX,centerY,r);
    drawLineAzim(g2d);
    drawLineEle(g2d);

}
```

Comment: As I said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539169/how-to-draw-the-radius-of-a-circle-without-it-being-shorter-or-larger-than-the-c/48548823?noredirect=1#comment84166832_48548823) and showed in my answer to your other question, you need to override `paintComponent()` not `paintComponentS()`. That method belongs to `JPanel` and that's why I extended from it.

Comment: (1-) `recently frakcool said it is not paintComponents method, it is paintComponent method.` - so why are you still implementing the wrong method??? Did you even search the forum for other examples using the `paintComponent(...)` method???

Comment: For better help sooner (re)read the [mcve] guide

Comment: But I am unable to get paintComponent method please Help . Where should I look for it.?

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the wrong method. Get rid of the "s" at the end of the method name. You need to override `paintComponent(...)`.

But, you also need to override the `paintComponent(...)` method of a `JPanel`, You can't just add the method to your class and expect it to work. This is Java 101.

Start with the working examples found in the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)